# CSS multiple transform to same element during different event

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a set of link tags that appear on page load with translate3D. This works perfectly fine. But I need the link tags to either scale on it's hover. Which doesn't work directly.

---

Is there a way to achieve it with just CSS? 
Here is the code :

```css
.linkblock {
  margin: 20% 0;
}

.hlink {
  width: 12%;
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.hlink:hover {
  transform: translate(0px, -20px);
  color: red;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.fadeInUp {
  animation: fadeInUp 0.3s ease-in both;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1.0s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1.3s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 1.6s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 1.7s;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkblock">
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Code relevant to your question belongs directly into your question, not just dumped on an external site. Please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the use of `both` that allow you to keep the last state of your animation thus the transform inside the animation will override the one on the hover that will never get activated.

You can split your animation into 2 animation and use `both` or `forwards` with only `opacity` and you will be able to have your transition after the animation is done.

```css
.linkblock {
  margin: 20% 0;
}

.hlink {
  width: 12%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  opacity:0;
}

.hlink:hover {
  transform: translate(0px, -20px) scale(1.2);
  color: red;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes show {
  to {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

.fadeInUp {
  animation: fadeInUp 0.3s ease-in,
              show 0.3s ease-in forwards;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1.0s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1.3s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 1.6s;
}

.linkblock a:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 1.7s;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkblock">
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>

</div>
```

Comment: This method is not working with IE and Edge. Is there something else required? @Temani

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```css
.linkblock{
   margin:20% 0;
  }
.hlink{
  width:12%;
  height:60px;
  opacity:0;
  padding:0 10px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
  transform:translate3d(0,0,0); /* add it */
}
.hlink:hover{
  transform:translate3d(0,0,0) scale(1.2); /* add it */
  color:red;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6)
}
  
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from{
    opacity:0;
    transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);
  }
  to{
    opacity:1;
    /* transform:translate3d(0,0,0); */ /* remove it */
  }
}
.fadeInUp{
  animation:fadeInUp 0.3s ease-in both;
}
.linkblock a:nth-child(1){animation-delay:1.0s;}
.linkblock a:nth-child(2){animation-delay:1.1s;}
.linkblock a:nth-child(3){animation-delay:1.2s;}
.linkblock a:nth-child(4){animation-delay:1.3s;}
.linkblock a:nth-child(5){animation-delay:1.4s;}
.linkblock a:nth-child(6){animation-delay:1.5s;}
.linkblock a:nth-child(7){animation-delay:1.6s;}
.linkblock a:nth-child(8){animation-delay:1.7s;}
```

```html
<div class="linkblock">
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
  <a href="#" class="fadeInUp hlink">fsdfsdf</a>
</div>
```

Comment: we don't have transition

Comment: Thanks for the help. This does work but the transition is lost. The 'forward' option given above helps in that.

Comment: @Tom, no problem

Answer (score 0):

You want to animate with the `max-height` property.

Set the max-height to say 50px on hover
set the max-height on the property itself to it's original height

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonaspraem/Lsbc8h0t/11/)

Final css file:

```
.linkblock{
   margin:20% 0;
  }
  .hlink{
    width:12%;
    height: 60px;
    max-height: 60px; // add this
    opacity:0;
    padding:0 10px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
  }
  .hlink:hover{
    max-height: 50px; // add this
    color:red;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6)
  }

@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from{
      opacity:0;
      transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);
    }
    to{
      opacity:1;
      transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    }
  }
  .fadeInUp{
    animation:fadeInUp 0.3s ease-in both;
  }
  .linkblock a:nth-child(1){animation-delay:1.0s;}
  .linkblock a:nth-child(2){animation-delay:1.1s;}
  .linkblock a:nth-child(3){animation-delay:1.2s;}
  .linkblock a:nth-child(4){animation-delay:1.3s;}
  .linkblock a:nth-child(5){animation-delay:1.4s;}
  .linkblock a:nth-child(6){animation-delay:1.5s;}
  .linkblock a:nth-child(7){animation-delay:1.6s;}
  .linkblock a:nth-child(8){animation-delay:1.7s;}
```